# remove string between comma if contains None

Tags: python

I have this string :

```
my_str = "energie='E', Offre=None, segment='X', mode_de_paiement=None, statut_contrat='CC', statut_fel=None, fmr=None, payeur_divergent=None, type_de_conducteur=None, compte_duale_rv=None, plan_mensualisation=None, adm=None, multisite=None, occurrence='4'"
```

i want to remove from my string, col=None so the result would be using Pyhton

```
my_str = "energie='E',  statut_contrat='CC', occurrence='4'"
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)ting on a comma and then on equal sign is a starting direction

Comment: Why is `segment='X'` not present in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete all the elements in your string that contain `=None`,  you can use list comprehension and string methods that are built into Python.

You can split your original string `my_str` into items using

```py
items = [item for item in my_str.split(',') if not '=None' in item]
```

This  will create a list of all the strings you need. You can convert this back into a string using the `join` and `replace` methods in python

```py
my_str = ','.join(items)
```

The result will be all the key-value pairs in your initial string that do not contain `None`

Comment: When replicating the issue I ended up having 
``energie='E',, segment='X',, statut_contrat='CC',,,,,,,,, occurrence='4'`` which the replace fixed.

Comment: After some more testing on my end, you are correct. The replace is not necessarry. The list can be converted using just a join.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_str = "energie='E', Offre=None, segment='X', mode_de_paiement=None, statut_contrat='CC', statut_fel=None, fmr=None, payeur_divergent=None, type_de_conducteur=None, compte_duale_rv=None, plan_mensualisation=None, adm=None, multisite=None, occurrence='4'"

my_str = ",".join([x for x in my_str.split(",") if not x.endswith("=None")]).strip()
```